# Removing inherent space between two text commands in swift

Tags: swiftui, text

Example Code

```
var accuracy = 2
HStack{
     Text("Acc +")
     Text(String(accuracy))
}
```

Result: "Acc + 2"

Desired result: "Acc +2"

I want to know how to remove the space that is inherently the two texts or if there is another fix.

Comment: Why don't you just write `Text("Acc +\(String(accuracy)")`?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to combine two `Text`s together, you can just use `+`:

```
Text("Acc +") + Text("\(accuracy)")
```

This gives you a new `Text`.

The space comes from `HStack` having a default spacing. So another solution is to specify a spacing of 0:

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("Acc +")
    Text("\(accuracy)")
}
```

But this will also change the spacing of the other views in the `HStack`, if you have any.